# ROS nxt sound sensor?

Tags: ros, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I see that ros nxt package supports various sensors. I can't find anything for sound sensor. Is the sound sensor supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32224/ros-nxt-sound-sensor?/) by [Charuvahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2214/charuvahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sound sensor is not supported in ros, only sensors listed in http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros is supported

---

Originally posted by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) with karma: 22 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0